# Error when trying to publish database to Azure without clustered indexes

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, webmatrix

I'm getting the following error when trying to publish my database to my Azure site:

```
17:13:29: Could not publish the site. Unable to publish the database. For more information, see "http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=205387"
17:13:29: Error detail:
17:13:29: An error occurred during execution of the database script. The error occurred between the following lines of the script: "332" and "334". The verbose log might have more information about the error. The command started with the following:
17:13:29: "INSERT [dbo].[DBStatus] ([LastIndex], [LastUpdated"
17:13:29:  Tables without a clustered index are not supported in this version of SQL Server. Please create a clustered index and try again. http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=178587
17:13:29:   Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_SQL_EXECUTION_FAILURE.
```

This link explains the error: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/04/29/10004618.aspx

Is there an easy way to convert my database to have clustered indexes or should I just choose a host with SQL Server 2012 hosting?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I wouldn't change your hosting option simply due to this.  Add the clustered indexes.

There is a tool called [SQL Database Migration Wizard](http://sqlazuremw.codeplex.com/) which can analyze a SQL database and make a migration script and even move the data.  One of the things it will do is suggest a clustered index on tables that don't have them.  However, like any tool, make sure you look at what it is suggesting and see if it makes sense in your scenario.

My suggestion is to look at the tables that do not have a clustered index and determine a reasonable index to create.  A tool like the one above can make suggestions, but they are just suggestions and may not be exactly what your table would benefit from.

The requirement for clustered indexes for Azure SQL Database comes from the fact that they replicate the data in triplicate and the clustered indexes makes that a faster process.

Comment: Good advice +1. For information - the V12 preview version now (Jan 2015) lets you create a table that has no clustered index. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/sql-database-preview-whats-new/

Answer (score 3):

I've done these steps:

1- Get a list of Tables without Primary Key by running this query:

```
USE DatabaseName;
GO

SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id) AS SchemaName,name AS TableName
FROM sys.tables
WHERE OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID,'TableHasPrimaryKey') = 0
ORDER BY SchemaName, TableName;
GO`
```

2- Create Alert table scripts for all tables, add them a Identity field and make it Primary by scripts like this:

```
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tableName]  ADD identityFieldName BIGINT IDENTITY;  
 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[tableName]  ADD CONSTRAINT  PK_Table_identityFieldName_1    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (identityFieldName);
```

Repeat above query for all tables that does not have Primary Key